# String comparison fails while using Scanner

Tags: java, string, loops, input

I have looked online and all of the tutorials / questions have pointed me to this. I can't see why this isn't working. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
import java.util.*;

public class test {
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String textEntered = userInput.next();
        if (textEntered == "hello") {
            System.out.println("Hello to you too!");
        }
    }
}
```

I enter "hello" but nothing is printed. Also I have tried next() and nextLine();

Comment: I do not see the while loop in the snippet though ... did u want to go on a loop for user input ?

Comment: I have been watching some online youtube tutorial and he had not mentioned that and when I looked online, most used very similar code and I didn't realise that it was the if statement that wasn't working. Also, in the real code it was in while loop and I just simplified it which is why i tagged loops by mistake.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You've said "while loop" in your question title, but there's no `while` loop in your code. So it will only check the first token you type, not subsequent tokens.
2. In Java, you don't use `==` to compare strings, you use the [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method (or sometimes [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)).

   Change

   ```
   if (textEntered == "hello") {
   ```

   to

   ```
   if (textEntered.equals("hello")) {
   ```

   The `==` operator, when used with object instances (and `String` instances are objects) checks to see if the two operands point to the **same object**, and so it's not true if you use it to compare two *different* `String` objects that have the same sequence of characters.

Comment: that works! thanks a lot :) I used to c++ and just learning java and have to get used to a few things! Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 2):

In java you can not compare string by `==` operator , You need to use `stringOne.equals(stringTwo)`.

`==` will compare ObjectLocation where as `.equals()` compares actual string which is provided by `String` Class in java

Answer (score -1):

The reason it may not be working is because you aren't comparing the actual string values.

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html

Try using something like.

```
 if (textEntered.compareTo("hello") > 0) {
    System.out.println("Hello to you too!");
}
```

That might help you out.

Comment: That link that you pointed out says: "use the .compareTo() method to test for **unequal** comparisons". `.compareTo` returns 0 for equal objects.

Comment: Well you use that to test if the two strings are the same. If they are it will return a 1. If not then a negative 1. But either way both functions will give you the exact same thing that you want. The compareTo function can be used for not only unequal but equal as well. So it's better to know that then just hte equal function.

And what I was getting at mostly, was that Mikeecb's problem was an easy google search away. Hence why I said it might help you out.

Comment: Have a look at the Javadoc for `Comparable.compareTo()` to see what it's supposed to return.

Comment: compareTo

int compareTo(T o)    Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.